# abnormal behavior of parent activity after finishing child activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have `Activity A` and I am calling `Activity B` from `Activity A` using `setResultForActivity`.

Now in `Activity B` when I press `Done` button I am firing `finish()` and it returns to 
`Activity A` and it return down to `onActivityResult`. Now the issue is after when I fired `finish()` in `Activity B` , `Activity A`'s  `onCreate` doesn't get called and thats why

some of the custom listeners in my `ListView` isn't working , it seems that they are not bind.

so the whole activity respond pretty weirdly , can anyone has solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

Why a fourth answer? Because in my view, the others aren't fully correct.

Truth is, Activity `A` *could* have been destroyed in the meantime, or not. This depends on whether Android needs memory or not. So it *is* possible that Activity `A`´s `onCreate()` is called (along with the other lifecycle callbacks), or not. In the latter case, `onActivityResult()` is called before `onResume()`.

While for configuration changes, the most efficient way to preserve the Activity's state is via `nonConfigurationState`, if you want to prepare for a restart of your Activity after it has been destroyed, you can use the `InstanceState` mechanism, because while Android destroys your Activity `A`, it will keep its intent and saved instance state to re-crearte it.

This stresses the absolute necessity to place initialization *exactly* in the callback where it belongs.

To test whether your Activity logic works regardless of whether Android destroyed it or not, you can use the DevTools setting "Development Settings" -> "Immediately destroy activities". The DevTools app is available on AVDs and can also be downloaded from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Just place your onCreate() stuff in onResume() of Activity A except setContentView().

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a read on Android Activity Lifecycle : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html. onCreate() is only called when the activity is first created. You can do your list thing in the onResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

Activity A's `onCreate` won't get called because the activity has not been destroyed.  When an Activity regains focus from another activity, it's `onStart` and `onResume` get called, so I would put your bound listeners in those.  They will also be called when `onCreate` is normally called.

Comment: i tried to put it in a onResume and i tried to set the listener there but they didnt work when the child activity finishes

Answer (score 0):

After your child activity is finished() it return to execute onActivityResult which is in your case in Activity A. The onCreate method is not supposed and does not get called when killing of you sub-activity, a.k.a Activity B.

Please post some source code for us to work on and I will improve my answer! :)